# Passing "this" from Java Interface to another Class

Tags: java, android, eclipse, oop

Giving the following class of my android Project :

```java
Preview extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback
```

and

```java
A extends Doc
```

I don't really know how to ask and I know that this is not really good but I want that from Preview, I call an abstract method of Doc. In this Doc's method, I have to call a method of the previous Object of Preview.

**This is an example :**

From Preview.java :

```java
   Doc _doc = new A();
   private void myMethod() {
       this._doc.process(this)
   }
```

From A.java :

```java
@Override
public void process(Preview p) {
    p.processA();
}
```

**The problem is that I got an error :**

> The method process(Preview) in the type Doc is not applicable for the arguments (new Camera.PreviewCallback(){})

However, I can't change this judging by the fact that I want to call the method from Preview. I tried many thing such as cast etc. None of them works.

Thanks for your help !

PS : I am on Eclipse under Windows.

Comment: I don't see how a call to `A.process(this)` could produce an error message `...is not applicable for the arguments (new Camera.PreviewCallback(){})`. Can you show us some more code please?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Assuming you are calling `A.process(this)` from an anonymous inner class (of type Camera.PreviewCallback I presume, hence the error message), you have to write `A.process(Preview.this)`, since a standalone `this` refers to the inner class and not to the Preview instance.

Answer (score 2):

> The method process(Preview) in the type Doc is not applicable for the arguments (new Camera.PreviewCallback(){})

It simply means you are passing the object of `Camera.PreviewCallback` but in your method `public void process(Preview p)` You want an object of `Preview`.

If you have written this code in side an [anonymous class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html), then `this` won't point to the `Preview` class. It will point to the object of inner anonymous class.

Thus you need to write `A.process(Preview.this)`